# How to span the single column in an ASP.NET Gridview HORIZONTALLY

Tags: asp.net, templates, gridview, html, alignment

i have a Gridview with a single column which is a template field with an image and a label.

By default, the gridview expands vertically according to the items in the datasource.

But in my case most of the screen space is left unused and the page becomes extremely long.

So it'd be great if the one and only template field automatically becomes a new column (starts again from the top next to it's initial position after a fixed height) or SPANS HORIZONTALLY, not vertically...

i've done some searching and still can't find a solution for this..
any help would be great..!

i took 2 screenshots for a better explanation but the site won't allow me to post images yet :/

Comment: I think you are looking for the DataList control. Namely, the RepeatColumns property.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem for now...
in some tutorials i've seen that Datalist dosen't support paging while Gridview does.. which is why i chose Gridview at first.

still it'd be nice to be able to Repeat a gridview column horizontally :)

Comment: Can i add that as an answer which you will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the DataList control. Namely, the RepeatColumns property.